# Building a dynamic navigation system using json data returned from records

Tags: jquery, slicknav, jquery-ui-menu

I have decided to use slicknav to build a dynamic navigation system for a series of records for a fire alarm incident system. I have this system built in Lotus domino database and in this database I have a dynamic system of expandable sections by year, month and day.  This is suppose replicate that navigation this in my application.  After looking at different plugins I have decided to use slicknav. This is where my challenge comes in. I have to build this system from the records of the documents.  Here is the base of my system.
First here is the sample of my json data returned:

```
   {"firedrills":
     [
     {"alarmyear":2018,
    "alarmyearmonth":"2018-9",
"alarmyearmonthday":"2018-9-18",
"monthname":"September",
"alarmday":"18",
"alarmdatetime":"2018-09-18 00:15:00.000",
"inciNumber":"2018-599",
"incidentlocation":"FR2W"},
{"alarmyear":2018,
"alarmyearmonth":"2018-8",
"alarmyearmonthday":"2018-8-7",
"monthname":"August",
"alarmday":"7",
"alarmdatetime":"2018-08-07 19:08:00.000",
"inciNumber":"2018-537",
"incidentlocation":"Laundry"},
{"alarmyear":2018,
"alarmyearmonth":"2018-7",
"alarmyearmonthday":"2018-7-3",
"monthname":"July",
"alarmday":"3",
"alarmdatetime":"2018-07-03 08:15:00.000",
"inciNumber":"2018-464",
"incidentlocation":"FA5E"}
]}
```

Here is the html and jquery code I built to test statically:

```
  <div id="firedrillmainnavdiv">
        <ul id="firedrillmainul"></ul>
    </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'../json/getfiredrills.php',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
                var $firedrillmainul=$("#firedrillmainul");
                $firedrillmainul.empty();
                $firedrillmainul.append(
                    $('<li>').prop({id:"2018"}).text("2018").append(
                        $('<ul>').prop({id:"2018-ul"}).append(
                            $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-9"}).text("September").append(
                                $('<ul>').prop({id:"2018-9-ul"}).append(
                                    $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-9-18"}).text("18").append(
                                        $('<ul>').prop({id:"2018-9-18-ul"}).append(
                                            $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-599"}).append($('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).text("FR2W"))
                                        )   
                                    )   
                                )
                            )
                        ).append(
                            $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-8"}).text("August").append(
                                $('<ul>').prop({id:"2018-8-ul"}).append(
                                    $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-8-7"}).text("7").append(
                                        $('<ul>').prop({id:"2018-8-7-ul"}).append(
                                            $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-537"}).append($('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).text("Laundry"))
                                        )   
                                    )        
                                )
                            )    
                        ).append(
                            $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-7"}).text("July").append(
                                $('<ul>').prop({id:"2018-7-ul"}).append(
                                    $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-7-3"}).text("3").append(
                                        $('<ul>').prop({id:"2018-7-3-ul"}).append(
                                            $('<li>').prop({id:"2018-464"}).append($('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).text("FA5E"))
                                        )   
                                    )    
                                )
                            )    
                        )
                    )
                )

                $firedrillmainul.slicknav({
                    label: 'Fire Drills',
                    prependTo:'#firedrillmainnavdiv',
                    duplicate: false
                });   
            })
        })   
    </script>
```

This all worked with no problem.  Here is the code I built to build this dynamically.  I am using the id's to append the data at the right level of the menu.  The first iteration through the code works fine but then I cannot find the id's to append the code to on the following iterations.  Here is that code. 
I am only showing the logic of building the unordered list.

```
  $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'../json/getfiredrills.php',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
                var $firedrillmainul=$("#firedrillmainul"),
                    alarmyear="";
                $firedrillmainul.empty();
                $.each(data.firedrills,function(key,value){
                    if (alarmyear==""){
                      $firedrillmainul.append(
                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyear}).text(value.alarmyear).append(
                            $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyear+'-ul'}).append(
                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth}).text(value.monthname).append(
                                    $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth+'-ul'}).append(
                                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday}).text(value.alarmday).append(
                                            $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday+'-ul'}).append(
                                                $('<li>').append($('<a>').prop({href:""}).text(value.incidentlocation))
                                            )    
                                        )   
                                    )
                                )
                            )    
                        )
                      )
                    }else if($firedrillmainul.find("#"+value.alarmyearmonthday)){
                        $("#"+value.alarmyearmonthday+"-ul").append(
                            $('<li>').append($('<a>').prop({href:""}).text(value.incidentlocation))    
                        )
                    }else if($firedrillmainul.find("#"+value.alarmyearmonth)){
                        $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth+"-ul"}).append(
                            $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday}).text(value.alarmday).append(
                                $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday+"-ul"}).append(
                                    $('<li>').append($('<a>').prop({href:""}).text(value.incidentlocation))    
                                )   
                            )    
                        )     
                    }else if($firedrillmainul.find("#"+value.alarmyear)){
                        $("#"+value.alarmyear+"-ul").append(
                            $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth}).text(value.monthname).append(
                                $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth+"-ul"}).append(
                                    $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday}).text(value.alarmday).append(
                                        $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday+"-ul"}).append(
                                            $('<li>').append($('<a>').prop({href:""}).text(value.incidentlocation))    
                                        )   
                                    )    
                                )    
                            )   
                        )
                    }
                    alarmyear=value.alarmyear;

                })


            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  As I loop through the records I compare first the year, then month then day and build out from there.  Here is the code to loop through the data.

```
  $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'../json/getfiredrills.php',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
                var $firedrillmainul=$("#firedrillmainul"),
                    alarmyear="",
                    alarmyearmonth="",
                    alarmyearmonthday="";
                $firedrillmainul.empty();
                if(data.hasOwnProperty("firedrills")){
                    $.each(data.firedrills,function(key,value){
                        if(alarmyear!=value.alarmyear){
                            $firedrillmainul.append(
                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyear}).text(value.alarmyear).append(
                                    $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyear+"-ul"}).append(
                                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth}).text(value.monthname).append(
                                            $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth+"-ul"}).append(
                                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday}).text(value.alarmday).append(
                                                    $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday+"-ul"}).append(
                                                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.inciNumber}).append($('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).text(value.incidentlocation))
                                                    )   
                                                )   
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )    
                        }else if(alarmyearmonth!=value.alarmyearmonth){
                            $("#"+alarmyear+"-ul").append(
                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth}).text(value.monthname).append(
                                    $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonth+"-ul"}).append(
                                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday}).text(value.alarmday).append(
                                            $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday+"-ul"}).append(
                                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.inciNumber}).append($('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).text(value.incidentlocation))
                                            )   
                                        )   
                                    )
                                )
                            )  
                        }else if(alarmyearmonthday!==value.alarmyearmonthday){
                            $("#"+value.alarmyearmonth+"-ul").append(
                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday}).text(value.alarmday).append(
                                    $('<ul>').prop({id:value.alarmyearmonthday+"-ul"}).append(
                                        $('<li>').prop({id:value.inciNumber}).append($('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).text(value.incidentlocation))
                                    )   
                                )   
                            )    
                        }else if(alarmyearmonthday==value.alarmyearmonthday){
                            $("#"+value.alarmyearmonthday+"-ul").append(
                                $('<li>').prop({id:value.inciNumber}).append($('<a>').prop({href:"#"}).text(value.incidentlocation))
                            )    
                        } 
                        alarmyear=value.alarmyear;
                        alarmyearmonth=value.alarmyearmonth; 
                        alarmyearmonthday=value.alarmyearmonthday;   
                    })    
                }



                $firedrillmainul.slicknav({
                    label: 'Fire Drills',
                    prependTo:'#firedrillmainnavdiv',
                    duplicate: false
                });   
            })
        })
```

As you can see at each if and else if I step up the unordered list level and add the data based on the answer.